# How to change the path structure in index.html file from built Vue project?

Tags: vuejs3, browser-cache, vite

I'm having a problem with building file paths in index.html when I run the build command. My app is using vue3 + vite

An issue I'm facing is that the index.html file references to js and css files this way:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.js"></script>
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/vendor.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css">
```

But I need it to do it this way because my app is having problems with cache in browser:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.js?v=1.1.0"></script>
<link rel="modulepreload" href="/assets/vendor.js?v=1.1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css?v=1.1.0">
```

I know that using [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68046410/how-to-force-vite-clearing-cache-in-vue3) solves the cache problem. But it does change the filename every time I build my app. Since my case needed to keep the filename static to be able to pass through the firewall, something like that

What would I need to add/change in order to get the path structure I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using VUE 3? In VUE 3 there is automatic different URL for assets.
Like below
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.a6466445.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.9c914eb6.css">

Comment: I understand with hash to get that, as I said above why I have to keep the path and filename static, so I configured the rollupOptions: {
                 output: {
                     entryFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
                     chunkFileNames: `assets/[name].js`,
                     assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
                 }
             }
that's why the file name doesn't change. because if you change it, it won't pass through the firewall