# Browser Error after each build with vue 2 vite and vitepwa plugin on firebase static hosting

Tags: firebase, vue.js, hosting, vite

> failed to load module script: expected a javascript module script but the server responded with a mime type of "text/html". strict mime type checking is enforced for module scripts per html spec.

I get this error after each npm run build and firebase deploy. But when i clear the browser chache, the page loads normally, until the app gets rebuild app again.

This is my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- I tried deleting dist directory and rebuilding
- I followed instructions in the vite documentation:

[ViteFirebaseDocs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#google-firebase)

The fact that clearing the browser cache fixes the problem, at least temporarily, is a strong indicator that caching might be part of the issue, but vite should handle cashbusting itself right ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to force vite clearing cache in vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68046410/how-to-force-vite-clearing-cache-in-vue3)

Comment: Unfortunately not. The hashes are changed without workarounds...