Vite Not Reflecting Changes in Laravel Project with .test Domain
I'm working on a Laravel project and using Vite instead of Laravel Mix for my asset compilation. I also use Tailwind CSS for styling. The Herd app is used to create new Laravel projects, which typically sets up a domain with a .test extension (e.g., myproject.test).
The problem I'm facing is that when I run npm run dev, changes are not reflected in the browser. It seems like Vite is not properly updating the project. Here are the steps I've taken and my current configuration:

Installed Vite, Laravel Vite Plugin, and Tailwind CSS:
npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p


vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        host: 'myproject.test',
        watch: {
            usePolling: true,
        },
    },
});


tailwind.config.js:
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './resources/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/**/*.js',
        './resources/**/*.vue',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}


.env:
APP_URL=http://myproject.test


Blade Template:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel Vite</title>
    @vite(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/css/app.css'])
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>


Commands:
npm run dev



Despite these configurations, changes in the JavaScript and CSS files do not reflect in the browser. I've tried restarting Herd and clearing the browser cache, but the issue persists.
Additional Details:

Laravel Version: 11
Herd Version: 1.9.1

Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I think it may be a cache issue. Try Cache Busting.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68046410/how-to-force-vite-clearing-cache-in-vue3

Caching didn't help

Did you try to remove the server inside the vite config ? You can use vite with herd event without those configuration.

No please. Let me try now

Please it did not work

in your resources/css/app.css add
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

and maybe check your php version you're using in your project. If you using 8.3 be sure you have updated it, you can check it in Laravel Herd > PHP
